# I want to get two numbers as input and calculate all the possible differences in Python

Tags: python, math, euclidean-algorithm

When I give the input as 17, 19: I only get 17, 19, 2 but I expect all numbers below 19 to be given as output. Since we are dealing with primes we should get 1 as GCD.

This is my code:

```
a=[]
n=int(input("Number of elements in array:"))
for i in range(0,n):
    print(f"Enter number {i+1}: ")
    l=int(input())
    a.append(l)
print(a)


for j in range(len(a)):
    for k in range(len(a)):
        diff = abs(a[j] - a[k])
        if diff > 0 and diff not in a:
            a.append(diff)
       

print (f"The final numbers are: {a}")
```

Comment: Why would you expect all numbers below 19? You calculate the numbers 17-19, 19-17, 17-17 and 19-19 and take all numbers above 0, which is just 2.

Comment: Why do think primes or GCD is involved if you are calculating differences?

Comment: Are you trying to express all numbers below 19 as linear combinations of 17 and 19? If so -- use the extended Euclidean algorithm to express 1 as such a linear combination and just multiply the coefficients of that solution by `k` as `k` ranges over 2, 3, ..., 19.

Comment: @FirefightingPhysicist I want to see if it is possible to add the resultant 2 to the set and further subtract them from the initial numbers (17 - 2 = 15, Then 15 - 19 = 4, 15 - 4 =11 and so on. ) and create new numbers. I am not sure how to do that. 

If the input is 20 and 12, I get 20, 12, 8 and 4 correctly.

Comment: @Flow I think it is something called the Euclidean algorithm. It reduces to the GCD of the two numbers. I had been just learning about it and wanted to try creating a program for it. 

I think when we are subtracting two primes (17, 19), a multiplicative factor won't come about, so we would end up with 1 as the end to the algorithm.

Comment: @JohnColeman Not a linear combination. There is a learning module for 8th standard students called Euclid's game where 2 players play. Each give a number (ex: 20, 12). Player 1 turn: 20 -12 : gives 8. Player 2 turn: 20 - 8 : gives 12 but it is already in the set (20,12,8) so 12 - 8 = 4. So the final set is (20,12,8,4). The player who gives the last number wins. This is how the module goes. 

I don't want the game here, but all the possible values from this algorithm to be printed out.

So incase of 17, 19: 2, 15, 13, 4, 9, 6, 3, 1, 18, 16, 12, 10, 5, 8, 7, 14, 11

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here.

First `len(a)` in

```
for j in range(len(a)):
    for k in range(len(a)):
        diff = abs(a[j] - a[k])
        if diff > 0 and diff not in a:
            a.append(diff)
```

is evaluated once. If you append new elements to a, they will not be considered for further calculations. However you would like to calculate further differences.

Second, you should read about the Euclidean algorithm since it is not working as you are describing it. (Wikipedia for example also includes pseudocode implementations of it).
For the difference based version of it (there is also a division based one), you always replace the larger of the two values by their difference:
(19, 17) -> (17, 2) -> (15, 2) -> ... -> (3,2) -> (2, 1) -> (1, 1). Therefore the GCD is 1.

The sequence you are looking for thus should be 19, 17, 2, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1.

Also there is no need to ask for the number of elements of the array if you want to recreate that algorithm, since it always needs 2 elements.